# Can't use Astropy on Spyder

Tags: python, spyder, astropy

I'm trying to use Astropy to view and manipulate data from a fits file but keep getting ModuleNotFoundError. I've used pip install astropy and I can see that it's there with python -m pip list but still get the same error.

If it's relevant I recently uninstalled anaconda and redownloaded just Spyder and Miniconda and am using 64-bit Python 3.9

Any advice or alternatives would be appreciated.

Comment: which Python interpreter is Spyder using (Preferences  -> Python interpreter)? did you make sure that `astropy` is installed to the directory of *that* interpreter?

Comment: Ditto @MrFuppes there is probably nothing special about astropy in this case.  Almost all `ModuleNotFound` issues when it comes to using an IDE are making sure you are installing the package in the same Python interpreter / environment that the IDE is using.